# Term for paying beyond the contract limit

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for one word for situation explained as under:

1. We (My Company) have a contractor.
2. His contract amount is $ XYZ per annum.
3. As the year ended he was already paid an amount "beyond contract" limit.

What should this amount be called? "Extra amount paid" or "Amount paid beyond contract limit" or what?

Is there exists any single or hyphenated word for this situation?

Comment: How about bonus?

Comment: That would be an amount paid specifically as a reward, not just payments above contract amounts

Comment: *exceeding* or *in excess of* are common ways to refer to such expenditures.

Comment: Over and above?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for "overpayment", or "overcharged" or "bonus"?

If he billed you the correct amount, but you paid more then it was an **[overpayment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overpayment)**.

If he billed you too much, then you were **[overcharged](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overcharged)**.

If he billed you the correct amount, and you paid him the correct amount and then added more (not in error) for his exceptional performance; then it might be called a **[bonus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bonus)**.

Answer (score -1):

using "above and beyond" the contracted amount can emphasize this.